# Scraping XML data with BS4 "lxml"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml, elementtree

Trying to solve problem very similar to this one:

[[Scraping XML element attributes with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968565/scraping-xml-element-attributes-with-beautifulsoup][1])

I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/latest.xml')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
for ce in soup.find_all("Cell"):
    print(ce["cell_value1"])
```

The code runs without error but does not print any values to the terminal.

I want to extract the "cell_value1" data noted above for the whole page so I have something like this:

```
2468.58
3061.58
376.64
and so on...
```

The format of my XML file is the same as the sample in the solution from the question noted above. I identified the appropriate attribute tag specific the attribute I want to scrape. Why are the values not printing to the terminal?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're parsing this file in HTML mode, which means the tags end up named `'cell'` instead of `'Cell'`. So, you *could* just search with `'cell'`—but the right answer is to parse in XML mode.

To do this, just use `'xml'` as your parser instead of `'lxml'`. (It's a little non-obvious that `'lxml'` means "`lxml` in HTML mode" and `xml` means "`lxml` in XML mode", but it is [documented](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).)

This is explained in [Other parser problems](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems):

> Because [HTML tags and attributes are case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax), all three HTML parsers convert tag and attribute names to lowercase. That is, the markup `<TAG></TAG>` is converted to `<tag></tag>`. If you want to preserve mixed-case or uppercase tags and attributes, you’ll need to [parse the document as XML](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml).

---

Your code is still fail because of a second problem: some of the `Cell` nodes are empty, and do not have a `cell_value1` attribute to print out, but you're trying to print it out unconditionally.

So, what you want is something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
for ce in soup.find_all("Cell"):
    try:
        print(ce["cell_value1"])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: You could use 'cell_value1' as a keyword argument and make your code a little shorter, eg `soup.find_all("Cell", cell_value1=True)`. But that's not at issue, +1