# Unexpectedly renaming field in file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, rss, lxml

I'm using Python BS4/lxml to parse an xml-formatted RSS feed (specifically https://itch.io/games/on-sale.xml). I'm finding that in the transition from Requests receiving the page data and BS4 reading it from text, the name of the link field is being changed. Specifically, res.text contains `...</saleends><link>https://foo.itch.io/bar</link><description>...` but reading it into BS4/lxml and printing that results in `...</saleends><link/>https://foo.itch.io/bar<description>...`, which BS4 is unable to parse correctly. My code is available [here](https://github.com/tauqua/claim_itch/blob/1338e0e084798ac1d2ca7af2fc04f0bd44f4c0db/claim_itch.py), line 237.

I can provide a stripped-down version of the project without the login and logging pieces for easy testing.

Edit with simplified code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("https://itch.io/feed/sales.xml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.item.link)
```

Expected behavior: Prints "https://itch.io/s/12345/foobar" (whatever the most recent link in the RSS is)
Actual behavior: Prints "<link/>"

Comment: Does it change like that? Tho it changes, does it matter a lot to u? What r u exactly trying to parse from the xml?

Comment: Yes, it changes like that even though I don't see why it would. As a result, the body of the link is unaddressable as far as I can tell, soup.link returns the string "<link/>" instead of the actual link that I'm trying to grab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lxml` is lxml's HTML parser and `lxml-xml` and `xml` are lxml's XML parser. (Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49639622/10011503) answer which points to [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) documentation)

So, instead of using `lxml` parser, you should use `lxml-xml` or `xml` parser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("https://itch.io/feed/sales.xml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml-xml')
print(soup.item.link.text)
```

Output:
`https://itch.io/s/38593/halloween-event-sale`